# setting default python version in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

Platform: Ubuntu 12.10

Python version installed: 2.7.3 (with ubuntu installation)

output of command (`which python`): `usr/bin/python`

recently i installed python2.6.6 (as some applications don't work on 2.7.3 version)

output of command (`which python2.6`): `usr/local/bin/python2.6`

by default command 'python' runs default version i.e 2.7.3

My requirement is to set python2.6.6 version to be the default one.

Thanks

Comment: did you consider update-alternatives?

Comment: @njzk2 yes i tried using update-alternatives but in that case I'm unable to import some modules which meant to be for version 2.7.x. In that case i wasn't able to even run pip command without errors.

Comment: How to install modules to a specific version ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu I would shy away from just changing the sym-links. Looks like the new way of doing this is `update-alternatives`, or `python-virtualenv` if you want to go that route. Check the responses here:

[how-do-i-make-the-terminal-run-python-3-1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14615/how-do-i-make-the-terminal-run-python-3-1)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with following command, but this could cause problems.

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python
```

Comment: what type of problems?

Comment: Many program in ubuntu assume that python2.7 is default. And if some of that program use the features that initroduced in python2.7, that program will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you perform the command `ls -al /usr/bin/python*`, you should see some symbolic links redirecting `python` to the latest version of python (2.7.X, in your case).  You can manually redirect this symlink to whichever version you like (2.6.X, in your case):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using open sourced software i would suggest patching your problematic scripts with a version selector. Kinda:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Build some *.pyc scripts out of xsd schemas
./generate_all_ds.sh && # Uses xsd files to build the *.py sources to be compiled
 python --version 2> python_version.foo &&
 PYTHON_VERSION=`cat python_version.foo | sed -e 's/Python //'` &&
 rm -fv *.pyc &&
 echo Will now execute \'pycompile synthetic_data.py ... tracked.py -V $PYTHON_VERSION -v \&\&\' &&
 pycompile synthetic_data.py ... tracked.py -V $PYTHON_VERSION -v &&
 sleep .001 && # Sorry cant remember why, wouldnt surprise me not existing reason at all
 rm python_version.foo &&
 echo 'Compilation batchjob completed successfully'
```

If this does not show the big picture then just think about how to make programs that behave according to what interpreters does each particular host have.

This is somewhat old software, nowadays i would have done it asking for `mktemp` when using foofiles.

God help me now.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of re-mapping internal python dependencies, change it temporarily and run the commands. Do:

```
alias python=/usr/bin/python2.7 (or any python version/path)
```

Once, the terminal is closed, doing `python --version` will give previous output.